# Unable to use pair<int, int> as key in set in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, set, std-pair

> Set is a Sorted Associative Container that stores objects of type Key.
>   Set is a Simple Associative Container, meaning that its value type, as
>   well as its key type, is Key. It is also a Unique Associative
>   Container, meaning that no two elements are the same.

I was trying to build a `set<pair<int, int>>` with the number and the position where it appears in the string as the `key`.

When trying to insert a `pair<int, int>` as the key for `set`, the insertion was not being successful when the first element of the pair appeared again although the `pair` was unique.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int> &lhs, const pair<int, int> &rhs)
    {
        return lhs.first > rhs.first;
    }
};
void print(set<pair<int, int>, compare> myset)
{
    for(auto iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();++iter){
        cout << iter->first << ' ' << iter->second << endl;
    }
}

void BuildSet(int num)
{
    set<pair<int, int>, compare> values;
    string number = to_string(num);
    for(int i=0; i<number.size(); ++i)
    {
        int quot = number[i]-'0';
        values.insert(make_pair(quot, i));
    }
    cout << endl;
    print(values);
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    BuildSet(98738);
}
```

And the output was :

```
9 0
8 1
7 2
3 3
```

With the entry `8 4` missing as the first element was being duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was very simple.

The `compare` method did know know how to handle in case the first element was already present in the 'set`. Modifying it to this resolved this problem.

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int> &lhs, const pair<int, int> &rhs)
    {
         if(lhs.first != rhs.first)
         {
             return lhs.first > rhs.first;
         }
        else
        {
            return lhs.second > rhs.second;
        }
    }
};
```

Here, the first element of the `pair` is compared first and in case of equality the second element is checked as opposed to the earlier one when only the first element was compared.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. Or just use `std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>`

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, That would be the clean way of doing it. I added this in case any body got caught up writing their own `compare` method.

Comment: Or just `lhs > rhs;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use functor:

`greater<pair<int, int>>()`

or 
`less<pair<int,int>>()`

as cmp function.
And `#include<functional>`

Comment: `less<T>` is already the default for `std::set<T>`, even if `T==std::pair<int,int>`.